# Clicar em botão via javascript puro

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar algum script simples onde ele procura por uma classe dentro da página e sempre que encontrar tal classe (esta sempre é um botão) o botão referente a mesma deve ser clicado.

Poderiam me ajudar com algum exemplo disso em Javascript puro?

Comment: Se fores procurar um botão pela class, ele vai dar um click em cada botão para o caso de existir mais do que um. É isso que pretendes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para simular um clique sobre um elemento, basta utilizar o método `click()` do mesmo.

```
var botoes = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) {
    if (botoes[i].className === "MINHA-CASSE") {
        botoes[i].click();
    }
}
```

Ou utilizando o `querySelectorAll`:

```
var botoes = document.querySelectorAll("button.MINHA-CLASSE");
for (var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) {
    botoes[i].click();
}
```

Mais sobre o método `click()`: [HTMLElement.click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click)

Answer (score 2):

Para clicar "programáticamente" num botão tem de chamar o `onclick` do elemento.
Pode fazer assim:

```
var botoes = document.querySelectorAll('button.tal_classe');
for (var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) botoes[i].onclick.apply(botoes[i]);
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Kx2t/

Pode também usar o `.call()`. O importante aqui é passar o `botoes[i]` para o onclick como `this`.

Comment: Alguém deu `-1` na minha resposta. Comentários são bem vindos :)