# Automatizar clique de botão

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Preciso automatizar a ação de um clique de botão por algum script (Javascript), poderiam me ajudar?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 

</head>

<body class="glitch-transition">
<main class="cd-main-content">
    <div class="center">
        <a href="#modal-1" class="cd-btn cd-modal-trigger">BOTÃO</a>
    </div>
</main>

<div class="cd-modal" id="modal-1">
    <img src="img/imagem.png" />
</div> <!-- .cd-modal -->

<div class="cd-transition-layer" data-frame="25"> 
    <div class="bg-layer"></div>
</div> <!-- .cd-transition-layer -->

<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Veja se [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27061/clicar-em-bot%C3%A3o-via-javascript-puro?rq=1) pergunta te ajuda

Comment: Acho que me expressei mal, na verdade, eu nao sei como fazer o script funcionar automaticamente, sem passar pelo o clique do botão, na verdade, quando a pagina é carregada, é preciso que seja executado automaticamente este clique do botão ao qual aparece na linha



<a href="#modal-1" class="cd-btn cd-modal-trigger">BOTÃO</a>


eu não sei como fazer isso. Já estudei alguns códigos e nada.

Comment: Ajudaria colocar o código JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Pra automatizar o clique do botão eu faria o seguinte:

Primeiro adicione um id ao seu botão

```
<a href="#modal-1" id="botao" class="cd-btn cd-modal-trigger">BOTÃO</a>
```

Depois dentro de um arquivo .js ou até mesmo dentro de uma tag  adicione este código:

```
 <script>
var botao = document.getElementById('botao');
botao.click();
</script>
```

Lembre-se de colocar esse script ao final da página.

Comment: Não funcionou ... algo a haver com o atributo href da tag <a></a> ? Existe alguma outra tag que eu possa usar no lugar da <a> ?
O script eu usei tanto no começo (antes do body) como no fim. Também não rolou

Comment: Hmm pode até ser. Você está usando alguma biblioteca/framework pra utilizar esses modais?

Comment: Uso o Modernizr.js 

Este é o meu script atual que se encontra no meu main.js, onde faço as referencias dos modais:

//open modal window
 modalTrigger.on('click', function(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();
  var modalId = $(event.target).attr('href');
  transitionLayer.addClass('visible opening');
  var delay = ( $('.no-cssanimations').length > 0 ) ? 0 : 800;
  setTimeout(function(){
   modalWindow.filter(modalId).addClass('visible');
   transitionLayer.removeClass('opening');
  }, delay);
 });

Comment: tente colocar esse script após a chamada do main.js, exemplo:  <script src="js/main.js"></script> <script>
var botao = document.getElementById('botao');
botao.click();
</script>  ou tente trocar a tag a por um button

Comment: ou se preferir coloque o código que te passei no final do seu arquivo main.js

Answer (score 1):

Como já possui jQuery e precisa do click do botão no load da página, você pode usar

```
$(window).ready(function(){
      // o que o botao faz
});
```

Detalhe:

A função ready só é chamada quando a página já está carregada e pronta para a execução do javascript

Answer (score 0):

Como você já tem jquery importado, você pode usar uma tag script antes do body.

Primeiramente declare uma tag button no seu documento HTML.

```
<html>
  ...
  <button id="seuId" />Botão</button>
</html>
```

Depois crie a tag script antes do body:

```
<script>
   $("#seuId").click(function() { /* execute seu comando aqui */ });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma função JavaScript, e a chame com `onload` no body

```
<body onload="funcao()">
```